# Did someone succeed to have pymqi installed under Cygwin with python3.6

Tags: python, pytest, cygwin, pymqi

I need to run pytest with pymqi under Cygwin in my Windows environment, the windows MQ lib are installed, and I was using some pip options to make the compiling processus finding the include and lib folder ... like :

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/cygdrive/c/Program Files/IBM/MQ/Tools/c/include" pymqi
```

but during link it is looking for the mqic_r dynamic lib, which is an MQ Lib variant under unixes versions, under windows there is no '_r' variants of the libs

```
creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.6-x86_64-3.6
creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.6-x86_64-3.6/pymqi
gcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base build/temp.cygwin-3.3.6-x86_64-3.6/code/pymqi/pymqe.o -LC:\Program Files\IBM\MQ/lib64 -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config -L/usr/lib -lmqic_r -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.cygwin-3.3.6-x86_64-3.6/pymqi/pymqe.cpython-36m-x86_64-cygwin.dll
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmqic_r: No such file or directory
```

Any clues ? maybe some way to change the pymqi compilation process ?

Best regards